# Re-attach deserialized hibernate proxies

Tags: java, hibernate, session, serialization, concurrency

I have retrieved a database proxy object `empP(domain class:Employee)` from hibernate using HQL. Now I'd like to serialize it(step1) into some file and then deserialize it(step2). Step1 and Step2 are in 2 different threads.

Problem in order:

1. I serialize empP in step1.
2. In step1 in does not serialize attached session of `empP` as in `((ProxyObject)empP).getHandler().session`, `session` is `transient`.
3. In a different thread, I deserialize `empP` as `empPDeserialized` and now have empP but with `empP.getHandler().getSession()` equal `null` . This is step2 with a different session.

Now, whenever I call `getter` from `empPDeserialized`, it throws `could not initialize proxy - no Session`.

In step2, I'd like `empPDeserialized` to attached to the current session so getter calls are successful.

Now, one stupid way I can think of is:

```
    ((org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer)((javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject)empPDeserialized).getHandler())
.setSession((org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
```

Question is, I'd like to know a best practice available to do it and with least sql calls in step2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `session.merge()`?

Comment: I did. But it does not attach any session to empPDeserialized's handler. May be because I have one more instance of this same db object elsewhere in step2 session.

Comment: session merge return a new object and you must use them instead of the merged one